# Set Selected Second component in UIPickerView to a NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, uipickerview

I have an `NSDictionary` of arrays and strings. I then have a `UIPickerView` with 2 components that gets its data from the dictionary. The first component is a string (from the dictionary), and the second one is an array (from the same dictionary).

In the `didSelectRow` method, I passed the first components item to a string successfully. What I'm having trouble at is setting the second component selected object as a string.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    values = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     array1, @"key one",
                                     array2, @"key two", nil];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if (component == 0)
    {
        rowSelection1 = [sortedValue objectAtIndex:row];

        for (id key in values) {
            if ([key isEqualToString:rowSelection1]) {
                [tempArray addObjectsFromArray:[values valueForKey:key]];
            }
        }

        secondComponent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [secondComponent addObjectsFromArray:tempArray];
        [self.pickerView reloadAllComponents];
    }
    else
    {
        rowSelection2 = [tempArray objecAtIndex:row];
        NSLog(@"%@", rowSelection2);
    }
}
```

The only part I'm having trouble at is at the else statement. I'm sure that is not how I am supposed to set rowSelection2, because it gave me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want:

```
rowSelection2 = [secondComponent objectAtIndex:row];
```

since it is your `secondComponent` array that contains the current contents for the 2nd component of the picker view.

This assumes that you populate the 2nd picker component with your `secondComponent` ivar.

You have a few other issues. Change the method to this:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (component == 0) {
        rowSelection1 = sortedValue[row];

        NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (id key in values) {
            if ([key isEqualToString:rowSelection1]) {
                [tempArray addObjectsFromArray:values[key]];
            }
        }

        secondComponent = tmpArray;

        [self.pickerView reloadComponent:1];
    } else {
        rowSelection2 = secondComponent[row];
        NSLog(@"%@", rowSelection2);
    }
}
```

Note the use of modern array and dictionary access. Note that there is no need to reload all components, just the one that needs reloading. Note how `secondComponent` is assigned. No need for the wasted allocation and the wasted array copy.